# Upgrade dotenv-webpack is failing

Tags: webpack, dotenv

I´m upgraded already webpack to version 5. After upgrading dotenv-webpack from the very old version 1.7.0 to current one 6.0.2 I got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:22)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:731:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:644:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

My current setup is:
package.json

```
"dotenv-webpack": "^6.0.2",
"ts-loader": "^8.0.17",
"ts-node": "^9.1.1",
"typescript": "^4.1.5",
"webpack": "^5.24.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
```

And my webpack configuration:

```js
const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  externals: [
    /^[a-z\-0-9]+$/, // Ignore node_modules folder
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add in `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    modules: [`${global}/node_modules`, 'node_modules'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: './src/env/.env.p',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Is it currently possible to upgrade to the latest version or which should I use ?

Comment: Which node version do you use?

Comment: I´m using node 12.20.1

Comment: Why do you think that it is related to dotenv plugin?

Comment: I think that it is related to modules: [`${global}/node_modules`, 'node_modules'], what is this `global`?

Comment: I figured out, after reverting this change (upgrade of dotenv-webpack to 6.0.2), on version 1.7.2 it works. This global is defined in the @types of node.